# LINQ Case-Switch in Where Query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

from what I can see it is possible to include the logic of a case-switch in a LINQ query but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it.

Basically I have three possible situations in which I want a `Where` clause to be different. The parameter that I take in is actually an int which can be 1, 2, or 3 so I just need to somehow correlate that to my where clause.

Thank you!

```
var parameter = Int32.Parse(Filter);
var queryString =
                from m in db.Movies

                join me in db.MovieEmployees
                on m.ID equals me.movieID

                join e in db.Employees
                on me.employeeID equals e.ID

                join r in db.Roles
                on me.roleID equals r.ID

                    //when parameter = 1
                    where m.Name.Contains(searchString)
                    //when parameter = 2
                    where e.Name.Contains(searchString)                      
                    //when parameter = 3
                    where r.RoleType.Contains(searchString)                              

      select new StarringViewModel { employeeID = e.ID, movieID = m.ID, roleID = r.ID };

      return View(queryString.Distinct().ToList().OrderBy(x => x.movieName));
```

Comment: Is it entity framework ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
where (parameter == 1 && m.Name.Contains(searchString))
                    //when parameter = 2
      || (parameter == 2 && e.Name.Contains(searchString))                      
                    //when parameter = 3
      || (parameter == 3 && r.RoleType.Contains(searchString))
```

Comment: It would probably make sense to have the parameter check before the contains to cut down on long searches

Comment: Thank you kindly! I didn't even think about doing that haha. I shall award you the answer once the timer expires :)